# Seeding remote images Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I would like to populate my app on heroku, so I need to seed images that I have uploaded on Amazon S3, and I can't figure out how to do...

I am using Carrierwave, with a multiple files uploader

Here is what I have in my strong parameters:

```
 private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:id, :title, :description, {attachments:[]})
    end
```

Here is how I try to seed for heroku, how can I make the url to be seeded?

```
Article.create!( 
        title:  Faker::Music.instrument,
        description: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(3), 
        attachments: 
         [ "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mysite/images_site/seeds/image_1.jpg", 
           "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mysite/images_site/seeds/image_2.jpg"]
        )
end
```

This is how I seed locally, and it works fine.

```
20.times do 
    Article.create!( 
        title:  Faker::Music.instrument,
        description: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(10),    
        attachments: 
         [ Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/seeds/image_1.jpg").open, 
           Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/seeds/image_2.jpg").open,
           Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/seeds/image_3.jpg").open, 
          ].shuffle)
    print "_"
end
```

## EDIT

After Carlos Ramirez III 's suggestion, it is still failing :(

```
➜  lesch git:(master) ✗ heroku run rails db:seed --trace                                                                                                          [2.4.4]
Running rails db:seed --trace on ⬢ new-lesch... up, run.1313 (Free)
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
D, [2018-09-15T13:55:37.031136 #4] DEBUG -- :    (7.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: extra arguments
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:136:in `open_uri'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:721:in `open'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
/app/db/seeds.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
/app/db/seeds.rb:12:in `times'
/app/db/seeds.rb:12:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:551:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:281:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:194:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You should pass I/O objects to CarrierWave uploader attributes

In the local example, you are calling `.open` on the file path which reads the file and returns a `File` object.

In the remote example, you are just passing URI paths, which are strings, not an I/O object like `File`.

## Reading a remote file

To read a remote file straight from a URI path, you can use the `open` method provided by the `OpenURI` module.

```
open("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mysite/images_site/seeds/image_1.jpg”)
```

Read the documentation here:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

NOTE: You may have to add `require "open-uri"` if you aren’t using Rails

## Seeding multiple remote files using CarrierWave

You can fix the Heroku example by wrapping the remote URI strings with `open` like so:

```
Article.create!( 
    title:  Faker::Music.instrument,
    description: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(3), 
    attachments: 
     [ open("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mysite/images_site/seeds/image_1.jpg”), 
       open("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mysite/images_site/seeds/image_2.jpg”)]
    )
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't work :( I tried with and with ou `trequire "open uri"` I pasted the error message above

Comment: Can you show me the exact code you are trying that’s resulting in the error you pasted above.

Comment: It seems that one of the uploaded picture has a problem and was messing up everything... I just removed it and it's fine now... thanks for your help

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Glad you were able to get it to work!

Answer (score -1):

Just create the database records in a more manual fashion. You'll need to ensure your S3 keys match your CarrierWave instance which generates the key structure.